# Python printing to an excel file

Tags: python, excel, file, store

I am trying to make a quiz which then stores the score of the user in an excel file however when I do this it writes all the scores that the user got through out the 10 question quiz - it gives me the score after each question but all I want is the name of the user and their **end score** to be put into the file. How would I do this in my code below?

```
import time 
import random 
question = 0 
score = 0 
name = input("What is your full name?") 
while True: 
    studentclass = input("What is your class name? Please enter 1, 2 or 3.")
    if studentclass.lower() not in ('1', '2', '3'): 
        print("Not an appropriate choice.") 
    else:
        break 
print ("Hello " + name, "welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz. This quiz is for eleven year olds. Use integers to enter the answer!") 
time.sleep(2) 
operands1 = list(range(2, 12)) 
operators = ["+","-","x"] 
operands2 = list(range(2, 12)) 

while question < 10: 
    operand1 = random.choice(operands1) 
    operand2 = random.choice(operands2) 
    operator = random.choice(operators) 
    def inputNumber(message): 
            while True: 
                try: 
                   userInput = int(input(message)) 
                except ValueError: 
                    print("Not an integer! Try again.") 
                continue 
            else: 
                return userInput 
            break 
    user_answer =int(inputNumber('{} {} {} = '.format(operand1, operator, operand2))) 

    if operator == '+': 
        expected_answer = operand1 + operand2 
        if user_answer==expected_answer: 
            print('This is correct!') 
            score = score + 1 
            question = question + 1 
            time.sleep(2) 
        else: 
            print('This is incorrect!') 
            question = question + 1 
           time.sleep(2) 

    if operator == '-': 
        expected_answer = operand1 - operand2 
        if user_answer==expected_answer: 
            print('This is correct!') 
            score = score + 1 
            question = question + 1 
            time.sleep(2)  
        else: 
            print('This is incorrect!') 
            question = question + 1 
            time.sleep(2) 

    if operator == 'x': 
        expected_answer = operand1 * operand2 
        if user_answer==expected_answer:  
            print('This is correct!') 
            score = score + 1 
            question = question + 1  
            time.sleep(2)
        else: 
            print('This is incorrect!') 
            question = question + 1 
            time.sleep(2) 
    if question==10: 
        endscore = str(score) 
        print ("Your score is {} out of 10".format(score))

    if studentclass == "1": 
        text_file = open("groupone.csv", "a") 
        text_file.write (name + "," + (str(score)+ "\n")) 
        text_file.close() 

    elif studentclass == "2": 
        text_file = open("grouptwo.csv", "a") 
        text_file.write(name + "," + (str(score)+ "\n")) 
        text_file.close() 

    else: 
        text_file = open("groupthree.csv", "a") 
        text_file.write(name + "," + (str(score)+ "\n")) 
        text_file.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if putting just two values into an excel sheet is efficient way. What about trying to use a simple file? You still can store the values in a Excel file using a third-party library: `xlrd`

Comment: @direprobs even if I do use a text file it still gives the score ten times which is the main thing I want to change

Comment: Please post working code.  Indentation is wrong, variables such as `operator`, `operand1`, `operand2` are never defined.

Comment: @marktolonen I haven't included my whole code - this is defined before. I have only added the relevant part of my code.

Comment: If the indentation is wrong, how can we tell what your problem is?  It is important in Python.  Can't reproduce your problem with code provided.  Most likely, you've got your file-writing code inside the while loop asking questions, when it should be outside the loop after asking all the questions, but can't tell.

Comment: @marktolonen I have added my full code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing score for each question since your condition to write into a csv file, **does not require the number of questions to be 10**. Indentation should do it:

```
if question==10: 
    endscore = str(score) 
    print ("Your score is {} out of 10".format(score))

    # Below are indented, meaning they are included UNDER the if statement above
    if studentclass == "1": 
        text_file = open("groupone.csv", "a") 
        text_file.write (name + "," + (str(score)+ "\n")) 
        text_file.close() 

    elif studentclass == "2": 
        text_file = open("grouptwo.csv", "a") 
        text_file.write(name + "," + (str(score)+ "\n")) 
        text_file.close() 

    else: 
        text_file = open("groupthree.csv", "a") 
        text_file.write(name + "," + (str(score)+ "\n")) 
        text_file.close()
```

Doing this implies that you will be writing to an output csv file only when questions have reached 10.